# Ionic Cordova Build to Android level 15

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Currently I am developing an ionic project to build on android level 15, so I set target-sdk to "android-15"

The problem is, when executing a build (ionic build android), I keep getting an error saying that class ClientCertRequest not found. I know that this class introduced at android level 21. My cordova version is 5.1.1. Does this mean that cordova has a dependency to android level 21?

or, is there any way to let it build to android level 15?

Thank you!

Comment: Install old version of cordova. then try to remove platform and add again

Comment: you have to set target-sdk to latest, and min-sdk to 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ionic does not support android api level 15.

> Ionic currently best supports iOS 7+ and Android 4.1+.

So the minimum sdk support you are looking for is `api-level 16`:

Though `cordova` does allow you to build apps on lower level-apis, but its strongly recommended that you use `Android 4.1+` for your ionic development.

[image]

Comment: When they say "Ionic currently best supports iOS 7+ and Android 4.1+.", I think they mean, Ionic is displayed correctly on that versions, but it should work on older versions too, as cordova currently supports iOS6 and Androd 4.0 and Ionic uses cordova, it should support them even if they arent displayed correctly

Comment: now what sense would it make to make a app which is not correctly displayed ? I have had experience in ionic, trust me, it does not even support android 4.1 and 4.2, properly. So why suggest someone to make an app in ionic that is clearly not supported in lower android. If you want to suggest then maybe suggest jquery mobile or cordova itself. Ionic will not be helpful in this case.

Comment: What I mean is that your answer doesn't make sense to the question. The problem is in Cordova, not in Ionic, he will have the same problem if he doesn't use Ionic. He has to set the target-sdk to be 21 or 22, and min-sdk to whatever he wants to support (16 if he wants to use Ionic)

Answer (score 4):

After creating  your ionic project , firstly  you should edit config.xml file like  below  ,then you can add android  platform by using "ionic add platform android" .

[image]